# How to write adb commands into a bat

Tags: android, windows, powershell

I have my laptop connected to an android phone.

I am doing a task many times, so I wish to write a `.bat` file to run the commands automatically.

```
adb shell
cd /sdcard/speech
rm -f *
```

The bat file only executed `adb shell`, the rest codes were not executed.

I guess because the it entered the android device so the commands did not run as usual.

One solution was `adb shell rm -f -r /sdcard/speech/*`

What if there are more and more complicated commands?
Is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your job with `adb shell "cd /sdcard/speech; rm -f *"`.

For more complicated jobs, you can put all the commands in a Linux shell script, use `adb push` command to push the script to your Android device, and run the script using `adb shell`.

For example, put all the commands in run.sh, then issue:

```
adb push run.sh /data/local/tmp
adb shell "chmod +x /data/local/tmp/run.sh"
```

After this you can run your jobs with:

```
adb shell "/data/local/tmp/run.sh"
```

You can include the above line in a `.bat` file.